# Will there by any copyright issue if we decide to add ACM Computing Classification System to our theses?

Tags: thesis, copyright, acm

Let us say that we decide to use [ACM Computing Classification System](https://www.acm.org/publications/class-2012) in the undergraduate and graduate theses from our department. These theses belong to the field of Computer Science and Engineering.

Will there by any copyright issues from ACM side?

There is an ACM Chapter in our department.

Comment: Why would there be a copyright problem with classifying documents? Are you saying you want to publish the classification list yourselves?

Comment: @JessicaB No, we simply want to put the classification somewhere in the opening pages of the theses.

Comment: But whose copyright are you afraid to infringe? (Please [edit] your question to clarify.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Copyright of ACM. Because the classification is their property. Edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copyright applies to the *text* of the classification, not to the use of it. Giving the classification of a document would be roughly like citing a result in another paper (and is the purpose of the classification). There would only be a copyright issue if you want to copy out part of the text.